# d3js animated pie chart using json

Tags: json, d3.js

I am trying to create an animated pie chart using a JSON file to store the data.

My JSON file is like this:

```
{"data":[
    {"ap": [
        {"floorratio": [
            {"floor":"Basement", "ratio": 0.20},
            {"floor":"Ground", "ratio": 0.20},
            {"floor":"First Floor", "ratio": 0.15},
            {"floor":"Second Floor", "ratio": 0.20},
            {"floor":"Third Floor", "ratio": 0.25}
        ]}
    ]},
    {"ap": [
        {"floorratio": [
            {"floor":"Basement", "ratio": 0.10},
            {"floor":"Ground", "ratio": 0.30},
            {"floor":"First Floor", "ratio": 0.10},
            {"floor":"Second Floor", "ratio": 0.15},
            {"floor":"Third Floor", "ratio": 0.35}
        ]}
    ]}
]}
```

and my HTML code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pie Chart Test</title>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
</style>

<body>

<label><input type="radio" name="dataset" value="0" checked> 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="dataset" value="1"> 2</label>
    <script>
    var width = 960,
        height = 500,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .innerRadius(0);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function (d) { return d.ratio;});

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var nodeSelected;

    d3.json("APCategories.json", function (error, data) {
        //initialise data
        floorRatio = data.data[0].ap[0].floorratio;

        var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(floorRatio))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        g.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.data.floor);
        })
            .each(function(d) {this._current = d;});

        g.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (d) {
            return d.data.floor;
        });
        //showing initial pie chart code ends here

        function changePieChart() {
            nodeSelected = this.value;
            newFloorRatio = data.data[nodeSelected].ap[0].floorratio;

            g = g.data(pie(newFloorRatio));
            g.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween);

        }
        function radioSelectedChange() {
            nodeSelected = this.value;
            changePieChart();

        }
        d3.selectAll("input")
            .on("change", changePieChart);
        function arcTween(a) {
            var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            this._current = i(0);
            return function(t) {
            return arc(i(t));
            };
        }


    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So at the moment I am only loading the first set of data because I am calling

```
floorRatio = data.data[0].ap[0].floorratio
```

but what I want to be able to do is to have something more along the lines of:

```
floorRatio = data.data[i].ap[0].floorratio
```

I have tried to do this in the changePieChart function, however I think the issue lies with the initialising of the data and I am not quite sure of the correct way to do it with JSON files.

Note: My json file is only a small example of a much larger version.

I want to create one pie chart that updates/changes but am unsure how to with JSON data.
What is the correct way of loading all of the data and then utilising it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write a function like forEach to browse through each element inside json data. Look at [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BYy3tSHGv5g5jhNmotJQ?p=preview) link. d will have the object i.e in this example (data.data) and i will hold the index of each object.

```
d3.json("json/APCategories.json", function (error, data) {
    //initialise data
    //floorRatio = data.data[0].ap[0].floorratio;

    (data.data).forEach(function(d,i) {
       console.log(d.ap[i].floorratio);
     // d.data = +d.data;
      floorRatio = d.ap[i].floorratio;
      console.log(floorRatio);
    });
```

EDITED : 
I believe you want to draw multiple pie charts for on number of "ap" objects see [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/GrR6xzvZDmUCjRX3m2fv?p=preview) for working demo.
[This link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ibAiMs9KZWXSqhgWav8c?p=preview) will show svg object which will update when selection changes.

Comment: Using that, how would I go about displaying the first data set?

Comment: look at this link - it will create multiple svg elements for number of objects and plot the data. http://plnkr.co/edit/GrR6xzvZDmUCjRX3m2fv?p=preview. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: the first link wasn't showing anything but I see now. I am trying to make an animated pie chart (one pie chart that changes/updates)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ibAiMs9KZWXSqhgWav8c?p=preview has the demo for one pie chart that update on change.